# In Google Analytics, why am I sometimes not seeing my utm_source and utm_medium from referral sources?

Tags: google-analytics

My company sponsored a blog post where the blog post directed users to our site, with links in the form of example.com/#home?utm_source=BlogX&utm_medium=CPL&utm_campaign=foo

We see some of our traffic in Google Analytics with referral source/medium correctly set as BlogX/CPL, but some of it seems to show in Google Analytics as coming from blogx.com/referral.  There aren't any links from BlogX to us that are missing the utm parameters, so how do we end up with that generic blogx.com/referral traffic?

We don't have that much traffic from that blog, so in one case, I can clearly see in GA that there is a visitor from city Bumblefeck with BlogX/CPL, and another visitor from city Bumblefeck with blogx.com/referral.  These are clearly the same person, but GA shows them as having different sources.  Does a session timeout affect our original utm_source/utm_medium?  Or is something else going on?

Comment: Note: I used BlogX as an example, but in fact this same issue happens with all of our sponsored blog posts on various blogs.  So it's not a problem specific to BlogX.

Comment: Really hard to say without inspecting your site, but the first thing I'd look for would be serverside redirects that strip of url parameters.

Comment: Shouldn't #home be placed after the query string, which includes UTM parameters? My guess would be based on the example URL, that GA is not recognizing UTM parameters, as it becomes part of the fragment, instead of query.

Comment: @kgrg - yes, it should, but unfortunately our partners just stick the params on the end of the URL we give them.  That doesn't seem to be a problem here though, as GA seems to get the params from location.href instead of location.search so it comes through correctly when I test those partner links.

Answer (score 0):

It can be users with browser extensions like UTM Cleaner, etc. who clean all UTM parameters in url.

Comment: This issue seems to happen too often, for too many separate users, to be the result of a browser extension that they would have to install.  It does make sense, but it just doesn't feel like the right answer in this case.

Comment: are you sure that your link have not redirects? maybe redirect clean your utm parameters?